# firefox and google-chrome need about 30 sec to launch any home page

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

this issue started 1 month ago. Let me explain. I'm running 12.04 x64 with unity. Connected through wireless. Every time I launch either firefox or google-chrome, these browser need at leat 25-30 sec to launch my home page (whatever homepage that be). Used to work perfectly. Opera works a bit better but still.... I already tried firfox in safe mode whithout any extension activated, switch from network-manager to wicd, erased all my configuration files under /home....nothing helped. Tried also to tweak my router...but nothing. To make it even more "funny" all my other laptops don't have this issue...in 1 sec there goes my home page....;)

Please...does anybody have a clue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you observe this latency to other network services or only HTTP ?

You can check latency with `ping` command to another laptop/server on your network.

You can also check the time to perform a DNS request : `time nslookup www.ubuntu.com`

Could you check your network configuration (`ifconfig -a`, `route`)

You can also clean your navigator's cache, cookies and so on... before doing tests.

Comment: this is what I get for time nslookup www.ubuntu.com:real 0m0.008s
user 0m0.000s
sys 0m0.004s

Comment: No lag on DNS... you can also use wireshark to look deeper about what's going on the network interface when you start the browser.

Comment: I'll try...but this tool seems to be far above my competence...tks

Comment: turns out that when logged in through live usb session....works like a charm...think I could use some fresh install...tks